# PostgreSQL: Is there a query or script for inserting data from database to another database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Just want to know if there's a way to transfer/insert data from different databases to other database in other machine?

Any script or query function to use for application to call/execute for inserting records?

Similar with the SQL Linked Servers process/setup.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has **Foreign Data Wrappers** which allow for cross-database / datastore communication:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers